# Using OneSignal and I'm trying to save player id to javascript variable, API unclear

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, onesignal

I have a OneSignal account hooked up to a Cordova/iOS app. I need to save the player id in my own database so I can send push notifications to specific users when tasks are due or events are happening.

I've looked at the API here: https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#view-device
 but I don't know how to call a JavaScript function to save the identifier to a variable. There is no example of this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: why you need javasript to get playerIDs? while add device only it will return playerID, then store into database. then retrieve from your database.

Answer (score 12):

I figured it out.

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {
                //document.getElementById("OneSignalUserID").innerHTML = "UserID: " + ids.userId;
                //document.getElementById("OneSignalPushToken").innerHTML = "PushToken: " + ids.pushToken;
                alert(JSON.stringify(ids['userId']));
            });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Their doc is very unclear, could not agree more!

Comment: Cheers, one digital beer for you

Comment: can we store playerID into Database?, Is playerID static?